# Github API check if a file exists, and then GET it if it does?

Tags: rest, github-api

Is there any way to do this through the github api? I've tried api.github.com/repos/name/repo/contents/path

But I'm a little confused as to what goes in contents and path. If it helps the file I'm trying to get exists on the root of the repo. So it's ./fileName I'm looking for. How would I go about constructing the GET url (unless I had it right, and its some other issue)

Comment: Show a [MCVE] of the problem you're encountering.

Comment: Doesn't GitHub prove a documentation of the API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi sorry I meant to update this, but if anyone makes the same mistake as I did its literally

```
api.github.com/repos/name/repo/contents/fileNameOrPath
```

And if anyone was wondering this led me to the raw url for the file, which I did a GET on and was able to get the content :).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete working example in case some users may benefit from it:

```
import github
from typing import Final
from github import Github, GithubException

GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN: Final[str] = "..."
github = Github(GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN)
repo = github.get_repo("star7th/showdoc")
composer_json_file = repo.get_contents("composer.json")
if composer_json_file:
    content = composer_json_file.decoded_content.decode("utf-8")
print(content)
```